# How to set image url of a div as its background in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have below code in my template, I would like to dynamically set background url value that come from django view

```
<div class="profpic" style="background:url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ objects.profpicpath }}');background-size:cover">
</div>
```

This gives the output as from the source code in browser as below

```
<div class="profpic" style="background-image:url('/UsersOpr/documents/documents/20150718/bd55adcd-9360-4a05-b506-18373805b600_20150718_152906.jpg');background-size:cover">
</div>
```

SO,

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }} is rendered with value '/UsersOpr/'

{{ objects.profpicpath }} with value 'documents/documents/20150718/bd55adcd-9360-4a05-b506-18373805b600_20150718_152906.jpg'
```

**What else am I missing ?**

Here is my **Settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '//192.xxx.xxx.xxx/d$/UsersOpr/'
MEDIA_URL = '/UsersOpr/'
```

I was searching extensively in the Internet on how to set the image url that is dynamically populated from django view and to be rendered in django template, but couldn't get through - tried using {{ STATIC_URL }} , {{ MEDIA_URL }} etc.,  and image path etc.,. but couldn't get

Comment: As you said, you can see the url in the source code.   But what I'm seeing is that the url is missing the http:// at the beginning.   Try setting a variable of IMAGE_SITE="http://192xxxxx" in your settings file and use that as your first variable in the image source.   <img src={{IMAGE_SITE}}{{IMAGE_PATH}}>   That should work.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I used {{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ students.profpicpath }} already.. it is not working :(.. MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT are set in my setting.py - there in my post –.. updated it

Answer (score 1):

After quite a lot of search, I could solve it finally.
Thought this could be helpful to someone who come across this scenario with the Media uploads.

Settings.py should contain below for sure :

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.template.context_processors.debug',
'django.template.context_processors.request',
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.media",  # Mandatory for Media file uploads
"django.core.context_processors.static",
)

MEDIA_ROOT = '//ipaddress or localhost/.../media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

When calling in the template.. it should be like

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ object.imagepath }}
```

and make sure that the media folder has read permissions to the user accessing the image object